# FiveM client lua. Problem with shops point

Tags: lua, fivem, grand-theft-auto

I have a problem with dots, when you enter a clothing store or a barbershop, the menu opens and works well. But after that, anywhere on the map, when you press E, the menu of a clothing store or a barbershop opens.

Here is the code itself, I myself do not know what the problem is there.

```lua
QBCore = exports['qb-core']:GetCoreObject()

local LastZone = nil
local CurrentAction = nil
local CurrentActionMsg = ''
local hasAlreadyEnteredMarker = false
local allMyOutfits = {}
local isPurchaseSuccessful = false
local PlayerData = {}

-- Net Events

RegisterNetEvent('QBCore:Client:OnPlayerLoaded', function()
    QBCore.Functions.TriggerCallback('fivem-appearance:getPlayerSkin', function(appearance)
        exports['fivem-appearance']:setPlayerAppearance(appearance)
        PlayerData = QBCore.Functions.GetPlayerData()
        
        if Config.Debug then  -- This will detect if the player model is set as "player_zero" aka michael. Will then set the character as a freemode ped based on gender.
            Wait(5000)
            if GetEntityModel(PlayerPedId()) == `player_zero` then
                print('Player detected as "player_zero", Starting CreateFirstCharacter event')
                TriggerEvent('qb-clothes:client:CreateFirstCharacter')
            end
        end
        
    end)
end)

RegisterNetEvent('qb-clothes:client:CreateFirstCharacter', function()  -- Event renamed so you dont need to change anything for this to work... hopefully....
    QBCore.Functions.GetPlayerData(function(PlayerData)
        local skin = 'mp_m_freemode_01'
        if PlayerData.charinfo.gender == 1 then
            skin = "mp_f_freemode_01" 
        end
        exports['fivem-appearance']:setPlayerModel(skin)
        local config = {
            ped = false,
            headBlend = true,
            faceFeatures = true,
            headOverlays = true,
            components = true,
            props = true,
        }
        exports['fivem-appearance']:setPlayerAppearance(appearance)
        exports['fivem-appearance']:startPlayerCustomization(function(appearance)
            if (appearance) then
                TriggerServerEvent('fivem-appearance:save', appearance)
                print('Player Clothing Saved')
            else
                print('Canceled')
            end
        end, config)
    end)
end, false)

AddEventHandler('fivem-appearance:hasExitedMarker', function(zone)
    CurrentAction = nil
end)

RegisterNetEvent('fivem-appearance:clothingShop', function()
    exports['qb-menu']:openMenu({
        {
            header = " | Clothing Store Options",
            isMenuHeader = true, -- Set to true to make a nonclickable title
        },
        {
            header = "Buy Clothing - $"..Config.Money,
            txt = "Pick from a wide range of items to wear",
            params = {
                event = "fivem-appearance:clothingMenu",
            }
        },
        {
            header = "Change Outfit",
            txt = "Pick from any of your currently saved outfits",
            params = {
                event = "fivem-appearance:pickNewOutfit",
                args = {
                    number = 1,
                    id = 2
                }
            }
        },
        {
            header = "Save New Outfit",
            txt = "Save a new outfit you can use later on",
            params = {
                event = "fivem-appearance:saveOutfit",
            }
        },
        {
            header = "Delete Outfit",
            txt = "Yeah... We didnt like that one either",
            params = {
                event = "fivem-appearance:deleteOutfitMenu",
                args = {
                    number = 1,
                    id = 2
                }
            }
        },
    })
end)

RegisterNetEvent('fivem-appearance:pickNewOutfit', function(data)
    local id = data.id
    local number = data.number
    TriggerEvent('fivem-appearance:getOutfits')
    Wait(150)
    local outfitMenu = {
        {
            header = '< Go Back',
            params = {
                event = 'fivem-appearance:clothingShop'
            }
        }
    }
    for i=1, #allMyOutfits, 1 do
        outfitMenu[#outfitMenu + 1] = {
            header = allMyOutfits[i].name,
            params = {
                event = 'fivem-appearance:setOutfit',
                args = {
                    -- number = (1 + i),
                    ped = allMyOutfits[i].pedModel, 
                    components = allMyOutfits[i].pedComponents, 
                    props = allMyOutfits[i].pedProps
                }
            }
        }
    end
    exports['qb-menu']:openMenu(outfitMenu)
end)

RegisterNetEvent('fivem-appearance:getOutfits', function()
    TriggerServerEvent('fivem-appearance:getOutfits')
end)

RegisterNetEvent('fivem-appearance:sendOutfits', function(myOutfits)
    local Outfits = {}
    for i=1, #myOutfits, 1 do
        table.insert(Outfits, {id = myOutfits[i].id, name = myOutfits[i].name, pedModel = myOutfits[i].ped, pedComponents = myOutfits[i].components, pedProps = myOutfits[i].props})
    end
    allMyOutfits = Outfits
end)

RegisterNetEvent('fivem-appearance:setOutfit', function(data)
    local pedModel = data.ped
    local pedComponents = data.components
    local pedProps = data.props
    local playerPed = PlayerPedId()
    local currentPedModel = exports['fivem-appearance']:getPedModel(playerPed)
    if currentPedModel ~= pedModel then
        exports['fivem-appearance']:setPlayerModel(pedModel)
        Wait(500)
        playerPed = PlayerPedId()
        exports['fivem-appearance']:setPedComponents(playerPed, pedComponents)
        exports['fivem-appearance']:setPedProps(playerPed, pedProps)
        local appearance = exports['fivem-appearance']:getPedAppearance(playerPed)
        TriggerServerEvent('fivem-appearance:save', appearance)
    else
        exports['fivem-appearance']:setPedComponents(playerPed, pedComponents)
        exports['fivem-appearance']:setPedProps(playerPed, pedProps)
        local appearance = exports['fivem-appearance']:getPedAppearance(playerPed)
        TriggerServerEvent('fivem-appearance:save', appearance)
    end
    -- TriggerEvent('fivem-appearance:clothingShop')
end)

RegisterNetEvent('fivem-appearance:saveOutfit', function()
    local keyboard = exports['qb-input']:ShowInput({
        header = "Name your outfit",
        submitText = "Create Outfit",
        inputs = {
            {
                text = "Outfit Name",
                name = "input",
                type = "text",
                isRequired = true
            },
        },
    })

    if keyboard ~= nil then
        local playerPed = PlayerPedId()
        local pedModel = exports['fivem-appearance']:getPedModel(playerPed)
        local pedComponents = exports['fivem-appearance']:getPedComponents(playerPed)
        local pedProps = exports['fivem-appearance']:getPedProps(playerPed)
        Wait(500)
        TriggerServerEvent('fivem-appearance:saveOutfit', keyboard.input, pedModel, pedComponents, pedProps)
        QBCore.Functions.Notify('Outfit '..keyboard.input.. ' has been saved', 'success')
    end
end)

RegisterNetEvent('fivem-appearance:deleteOutfitMenu', function(data)
    local id = data.id
    local number = data.number
    TriggerEvent('fivem-appearance:getOutfits')
    Wait(150)
    local DeleteMenu = {
        {
            header = '< Go Back',
            params = {
                event = 'fivem-appearance:clothingShop'
            }
        }
    }
    for i=1, #allMyOutfits, 1 do
        DeleteMenu[#DeleteMenu + 1] = {
            header = 'Delete "'..allMyOutfits[i].name..'"',
            txt = 'You will never be able to get this back!',
            params = {
                event = 'fivem-appearance:deleteOutfit',
                args = allMyOutfits[i].id
            }
        }
    end
    exports['qb-menu']:openMenu(DeleteMenu)
end)

RegisterNetEvent('fivem-appearance:deleteOutfit', function(id)
    TriggerServerEvent('fivem-appearance:deleteOutfit', id)
    -- TriggerEvent('fivem-appearance:clothingShop')
    QBCore.Functions.Notify('Outfit Deleted', 'error')
end)

RegisterNetEvent("fivem-appearance:purchase", function(bool)
    isPurchaseSuccessful = bool
end)

RegisterNetEvent('fivem-appearance:clothingMenu', function()
    TriggerServerEvent('fivem-appearances:buyclothing')
    Wait(500)
    if isPurchaseSuccessful then
        local config = {
            ped = false,
            headBlend = false,
            faceFeatures = false,
            headOverlays = false,
            components = true,
            props = true
        }
        
        exports['fivem-appearance']:startPlayerCustomization(function(appearance)
            if appearance then
                TriggerServerEvent('fivem-appearance:save', appearance)
                print('Player Clothing Saved')
                Wait(1000) -- Wait is needed to clothing menu dosent overwrite the tattoos
                TriggerServerEvent('Select:Tattoos')
            else
                print('Canceled')
                Wait(1000) -- Wait is needed to clothing menu dosent overwrite the tattoos
                TriggerServerEvent('Select:Tattoos')
            end
        end, config)
    end
end)

RegisterNetEvent('fivem-appearance:barberMenu', function()
    local config = {
        ped = false,
        headBlend = false,
        faceFeatures = false,
        headOverlays = true,
        components = false,
        props = false
    }

    exports['fivem-appearance']:startPlayerCustomization(function (appearance)
        if appearance then
            TriggerServerEvent('fivem-appearance:save', appearance)
            print('Player Clothing Saved')
            Wait(1000) -- Wait is needed to clothing menu dosent overwrite the tattoos
            TriggerServerEvent('Select:Tattoos')
        else
            print('Canceled')
            Wait(1000) -- Wait is needed to clothing menu dosent overwrite the tattoos
            TriggerServerEvent('Select:Tattoos')
        end
    end, config)
end)

-- Backwords Events so you dont need to replace these

RegisterNetEvent('qb-clothing:client:openMenu', function()  -- Admin Menu clothing event
    Wait(500)
    local config = {
        ped = true,
        headBlend = true,
        faceFeatures = true,
        headOverlays = true,
        components = true,
        props = true
    }
    
    exports['fivem-appearance']:startPlayerCustomization(function(appearance)
        if appearance then
            TriggerServerEvent('fivem-appearance:save', appearance)
            print('Player Clothing Saved')
            Wait(1000) -- Wait is needed to clothing menu dosent overwrite the tattoos
            TriggerServerEvent('Select:Tattoos')
        else
            print('Canceled')
            Wait(1000) -- Wait is needed to clothing menu dosent overwrite the tattoos
            TriggerServerEvent('Select:Tattoos')
        end
    end, config)
end)

RegisterNetEvent('qb-clothing:client:openOutfitMenu', function()  -- Name is so that you dont have to replace the event, Used in Appartments, Bossmenu, etc...
    exports['qb-menu']:openMenu({
        {
            header = " | Outfit Options",
            isMenuHeader = true, -- Set to true to make a nonclickable title
        },
        {
            header = "Change Outfit",
            txt = "Pick from any of your currently saved outfits",
            params = {
                event = "fivem-appearance:pickNewOutfitApp",
                args = {
                    number = 1,
                    id = 2
                }
            }
        },
        {
            header = "Save New Outfit",
            txt = "Save a new outfit you can use later on",
            params = {
                event = "fivem-appearance:saveOutfit",
            }
        },
        {
            header = "Delete Outfit",
            txt = "Yeah... We didnt like that one either",
            params = {
                event = "fivem-appearance:deleteOutfitMenu",
                args = {
                    number = 1,
                    id = 2
                }
            }
        },
    })
end)


RegisterNetEvent('fivem-appearance:pickNewOutfitApp', function(data)
    local id = data.id
    local number = data.number
    TriggerEvent('fivem-appearance:getOutfits')
    Wait(150)
    local outfitMenu = {
        {
            header = '< Go Back',
            params = {
                event = 'qb-clothing:client:openOutfitMenu'
            }
        }
    }
    for i=1, #allMyOutfits, 1 do
        outfitMenu[#outfitMenu + 1] = {
            header = allMyOutfits[i].name,
            params = {
                event = 'fivem-appearance:setOutfit',
                args = {
                    -- number = (1 + i),
                    ped = allMyOutfits[i].pedModel, 
                    components = allMyOutfits[i].pedComponents, 
                    props = allMyOutfits[i].pedProps
                }
            }
        }
    end
    exports['qb-menu']:openMenu(outfitMenu)
end)

RegisterNetEvent('fivem-appearance:deleteOutfitMenuApp', function(data)
    local id = data.id
    local number = data.number
    TriggerEvent('fivem-appearance:getOutfits')
    Wait(150)
    local DeleteMenu = {
        {
            header = '< Go Back',
            params = {
                event = 'fivem-appearance:clothingShop'
            }
        }
    }
    for i=1, #allMyOutfits, 1 do
        DeleteMenu[#DeleteMenu + 1] = {
            header = 'Delete "'..allMyOutfits[i].name..'"',
            txt = 'You will never be able to get this back!',
            params = {
                event = 'fivem-appearance:deleteOutfit',
                args = allMyOutfits[i].id
            }
        }
    end
    exports['qb-menu']:openMenu(DeleteMenu)
end)

-- Theads

CreateThread(function()
    while true do

        Wait(0)

        if CurrentAction ~= nil then

            if IsControlPressed(1, 38) then
                Wait(500)

                if CurrentAction == 'clothingMenu' then
                    TriggerEvent("fivem-appearance:clothingShop")
                end
                
                if CurrentAction == 'barberMenu' then
                    TriggerEvent("fivem-appearance:barberMenu")
                end

            end
        end
    end
end)

CreateThread(function()
    for k,v in ipairs(Config.BarberShops) do
        local blip = AddBlipForCoord(v)

        SetBlipSprite (blip, 71)
        -- SetBlipColour (blip, 47)
        SetBlipScale (blip, 0.7)
        SetBlipAsShortRange(blip, true)

        BeginTextCommandSetBlipName('STRING')
        AddTextComponentSubstringPlayerName('Barber Shop')
        EndTextCommandSetBlipName(blip)
    end
    for k,v in ipairs(Config.ClothingShops) do
        local data = v
        if data.blip == true then
            local blip = AddBlipForCoord(data.coords)

            SetBlipSprite (blip, 73)
            -- SetBlipColour (blip, 47)
            SetBlipScale (blip, 0.7)
            SetBlipAsShortRange(blip, true)

            BeginTextCommandSetBlipName('STRING')
            AddTextComponentSubstringPlayerName('Clothing Store')
            EndTextCommandSetBlipName(blip)
        end
    end
end)

CreateThread(function()
    while true do
        local playerCoords, isInClothingShop, isInPDPresets, isInBarberShop, currentZone, letSleep = GetEntityCoords(PlayerPedId()), false, false, nil, true
        local sleep = 2000
        for k,v in pairs(Config.ClothingShops) do
            local data = v
            local distance = #(playerCoords - data.coords)

            if distance < Config.DrawDistance then
                sleep = 500
                if distance < data.MarkerSize.x then
                    isInClothingShop, currentZone = true, k
                end
            end
        end

        for k,v in pairs(Config.BarberShops) do
            local distance = #(playerCoords - v)

            if distance < Config.DrawDistance then
                sleep = 500
                if distance < Config.MarkerSize.x then
                    isInBarberShop, currentZone = true, k
                end
            end
        end
        
        
        if (isInClothingShop and not hasAlreadyEnteredMarker) or (isInClothingShop and LastZone ~= currentZone) then
            hasAlreadyEnteredMarker, LastZone = true, currentZone
            CurrentAction     = 'clothingMenu'
            exports['qb-drawtext']:DrawText('[E] Clothing Menu','left')
        end

        if (isInBarberShop and not hasAlreadyEnteredMarker) or (isInBarberShop and LastZone ~= currentZone) then
            hasAlreadyEnteredMarker, LastZone = true, currentZone
            CurrentAction     = 'barberMenu'
            exports['qb-drawtext']:DrawText('[E] Barber Menu','left')
        end

        if not isInClothingShop and not isInBarberShop and hasAlreadyEnteredMarker then
            hasAlreadyEnteredMarker = false
            sleep = 0
            TriggerEvent('fivem-appearance:hasExitedMarker', LastZone)
            exports['qb-drawtext']:HideText()
        end
        Wait(sleep)
    end
end)

-- Command(s)

RegisterCommand('reloadskin', function()
    local playerPed = PlayerPedId()
    local maxhealth = GetEntityMaxHealth(playerPed)
    local health = GetEntityHealth(playerPed)
    QBCore.Functions.TriggerCallback('fivem-appearance:getPlayerSkin', function(appearance)
        exports['fivem-appearance']:setPlayerAppearance(appearance)
    end)
    for k, v in pairs(GetGamePool('CObject')) do
        if IsEntityAttachedToEntity(PlayerPedId(), v) then
            SetEntityAsMissionEntity(v, true, true)
            DeleteObject(v)
            DeleteEntity(v)
        end
    SetPedMaxHealth(PlayerId(), maxhealth)
    Citizen.Wait(1000) -- Safety Delay
    SetEntityHealth(PlayerPedId(), health)
    end
end)

-- Testing Command

RegisterCommand('clothingmenu', function()
    local config = {
        ped = true,
        headBlend = true,
        faceFeatures = true,
        headOverlays = true,
        components = true,
        props = true,
    }
    exports['fivem-appearance']:startPlayerCustomization(function (appearance)
        if (appearance) then
            TriggerServerEvent('fivem-appearance:save', appearance)
            print('Player Clothing Saved')
            Wait(1000) -- Wait is needed to clothing menu dosent overwrite the tattoos
            TriggerServerEvent('Select:Tattoos')
        else
            print('Canceled')
            Wait(1000) -- Wait is needed to clothing menu dosent overwrite the tattoos
            TriggerServerEvent('Select:Tattoos')
        end
    end, config)
end, false)
```

I tried to set the boundaries of the vectors, it did not help. Tried to find the error but couldn't...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the `CurrentAction` variable is never being reset to `nil`, so the thread you started to monitor for that keypress continues to "react" to it with the last visited store.

The way the code is written, it appears as though it is meant to be reset to `nil` only when the when `hasExitedMarker` function is triggered, but you only trigger this in one place - and it is only conditionally run only if `hasAlreadyEnteredMarker` is set to true when a shop is detected as being exited. I have a feeling that variable is not being properly maintained.

You can see how this quickly turns into a daisy-chain of state that must be maintained "just so".

Without undergoing a massive debugging session on your behalf, I can only suggest you debug these variables by outputting them to the screen, and watching for when they are set and properly unset (or not).

Higher level advice might be to add whatever routine you use to detect entry/exit into barber/clothing shops to a standalone function you can call directly from the keypress event handler, and skip handling it if you are not in the expected location. This won't solve your original problem of your application state falling into disrepair, but it gives you a chance to "fix" your state on keypress if it turns out you are handling it when you shouldn't be.